# how to check overfitting in my ML/ DL model

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-networks

My data contains 2 classes the negative one contains 292 samples the positive one contains 192. I trained my model with 5 ML/DL models:

```
data = data.drop(['filename'],axis=1)#Encoding the Labels
genre_list = data.iloc[:, -1]
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(genre_list)#Scaling the Feature columns
X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values

scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(data.iloc[:, :-1], dtype = float))
#Dividing data into training and Testing set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0, test_size=0.22)
```

Our models are:

```
    
    #GLM
    linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV(),
    
    #Navies Bayes
    naive_bayes.GaussianNB(),
    
    #Nearest Neighbor
    neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(),
    
    #SVM
    svm.SVC(probability=True)
    
    ]
```

and then the training of the models:

```
MLA_columns = []
MLA_compare = pd.DataFrame(columns = MLA_columns)


row_index = 0
for alg in MLA:
    
    
    predicted = alg.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
    fp, tp, th = roc_curve(y_test, predicted)
    MLA_name = alg.__class__.__name__
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index,'MLA Name'] = MLA_name
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Train Accuracy'] = round(alg.score(X_train, y_train), 4)
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Test Accuracy'] = round(alg.score(X_test, y_test), 4)
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Precission'] = precision_score(y_test, predicted)
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA Recall'] = recall_score(y_test, predicted)
    MLA_compare.loc[row_index, 'MLA AUC'] = auc(fp, tp)


    row_index+=1
    
MLA_compare.sort_values(by = ['MLA Test Accuracy'], ascending = False, inplace = True)    
MLA_compare
```

Their evaluations metrics are:
[image]

Their confusion matrix:
[image]

[image]

The auc/roc curbe:
[image]

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy','mse', 'mae','mape', 'cosine_proximity'])
classifier = model.fit(X_train,
                    y_train,
                    validation_split=0.33,
                    epochs=20,
                    batch_size=128,
                      verbose=0)
```

```
pred_train= model.predict(X_train)
scores = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy on training data: {} \n Error on training data: {}'.format(scores[1], 1 - scores[1])) 

pred_test= model.predict(X_test)
scores2 = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy on test data: {} \n Error on test data: {}'.format(scores2[1], 1 - scores2[1]))
```

- Accuracy on training data: 0.9792899489402771
- Error on training data: 0.0207100510597229
- Accuracy on test data: 0.9383561611175537
- Error on test data: 0.06164383888244629

[image]

Do I have overfitting in my models? and which model is the best?

Comment: By definition overfitting is when your model works much better on train data than on test data. In simplest cases (like yours) the overfitting should come gradually, epoch after epoch your model has better and better training score; and worse and worse test score. Now read your plots - validation accuracy still goes up even on the last epochs, so I see no overfitting.

Comment: As a side note - it's theoretically possible for models (typically deep neural networks) to return back to good test performance even after some period of overfitting, but it's unlikely with such classical models as LR, GaussianNB, KNN, SVM, etc